# Jmeter response time peaks every ~5 minutes

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

I have an issue when running load tests using JMeter - the response peaks every ~5 minutes. These response time peaks are repeating in every run and for different processes or even single endpoints.
Below is the response time graph for one of the endpoints I am testing. The graph shows merged results of 4 different runs and the response time peaks are present in all of them - repeating every ~5 minutes.
The test configuration is 100 users, ramp-up time 3500s and thread duration 3600s.

[Response time graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amw4c.png)

This can also be observed in response time vs threads graph:
[Response time vs threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYkyx.png)

This looks like some JMeter misconfiguration, but I couldn't find any relevant info for such repeating peaks.

Answer (score 0):

Re-run your test with:

1. Monitoring your operating system metrics like CPU, RAM, Network, Disk, etc. usage as it might be a third-party periodic activity which has an impact. The majority of operating systems have monitoring toolchains out of the box, if yours don't - you can consider using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
2. Doing the same for the JVM metrics using a tool like [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) or equivalent (the aforementioned JMeter PerfMon Plugin can read the statistics via [JMX](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md#jmx-metrics)) as the pattern you're getting looks like a [full GC](https://plumbr.io/blog/garbage-collection/minor-gc-vs-major-gc-vs-full-gc)
3. Doing the same for the system under test as it might be the case JMeter works just fine and the problem is on the application side.
4. If you confirm that the problem is in JMeter:

   - Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
   - If you have followed them already and the issue is still there - you might have to switch to [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)